# What alternatives exist get past the GENERATESERIES limitation of 1,000 values?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is there a way to enter data into Power BI with precision? For example, if I want to enter $1,575.75 or 6.72% into a slicer or some alternative.

I am currently using a slicer with the GENERATESERIES that lets me enter values, but the limitation is 1,000 possibilities and I am trying to find a workaround.

I tried using `GENERATESERIES(-75,175,.25)` but I am limited by what values can be entered/displayed due to Power BI limitations (sampling pool). I would like to enter *any* number without restriction to the increment value or range of numbers in the series.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to `UNION` several `GENERATESERIES`, but I don't think it will work since it's not a limitation of `GENERATESERIES` but the `What-if parameter` framework:

```
Values = 
UNION ( 
    GENERATESERIES ( 0, 999, 1 ),
    GENERATESERIES ( 1000, 1999, 1 )
)
```

But this limitation for `What-if parameter` is indeed an unfortunate one. It makes the functionality less useful than it could be. Ideally would wish for an implementation that does not rely on persisting a table in the data model, but an actual "injected" parameter into whatever queries are generated using the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to my own question that I have successfully implemented. The solution is to create a table with the columns of values and have the slicer reference those values. Here are the steps to take:

1. Create a table with a column called "NumSeries" with the number series. In my case, I used values from 0 to 750M in 500 increments.
2. Create a slicer visual and add the "NumSeries" column to the the field item.
3. Create a measure that takes the `MAXVALUE` from the slicer and use within your Power BI as needed.

Measure =

VAR `MaxValue` = `MAX`(NumberSeries[NumSeries])
RETURN
MaxValue

I used with a table with over 750K rows and it populated the correct value and was represented within the MaxValue. Thank you.